# changing line if user exceeds a specific number of characters

Tags: c++, pointers, user-input, dynamic-memory-allocation

i am doing an assignment in which i am creating a text editor working on the primary memory. i am not allowed to use file handling neither i am allowed to use string class the string library or the cstring library.
now what i have to achieve is that a single line contains only 60 characters and if the user exceeds 60 characters in input it should automatically shift to the next line along with it i also have to display the line numbers while the user is giving input
my code is here

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char***files=new char**[50];
    char**fileNames=new char*[50];
    int fileCount=0;
    while (true)
    {
        int selector=0;
        cout<<"MacMAds Notepad"<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"Press 1. To Create a new file"<<endl;
        cout<<"Press 2. To View an existing file by giving file name"<<endl;
        cout<<"Press 3. To edit an existing file by giving its name"<<endl;
        cout<<"Press 4. To copy an existing file to a new file"<<endl;
        cout<<"Press 5. To delete an existing file by giving its name"<<endl;
        cout<<"Press 6. To view listof all files with the names"<<endl;
        cout<<"Press7. To Exit"
        cin>>selector;
        if (selector==7)
            break;
        if (selector==1)
        {
            cout<<"Please enter the name of file: ";
            cin>>fileNames[fileCount];
            int nLines=0;
            cout<<"Please enter the number of lines for "<<fileNames[fileCount]<<": ";
            cin>>nLines;
            files[fileCount]=new char*[nLines];
            for (int i=0;i<nLines;i++)
            {
                files[fileCount][i]=new char[61];
                cin.getline(files[fileCount][i],60)
            }

                    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We won't write that code for you. Give it a try yourself, and we might give you help with specific problems you encounter.

Comment: actually i want to know which libraries and functions can achieve this as i dnt thnk cin.getline will achieve this

Comment: You are restricted not to use any of these? I don't get what you want then.

Comment: basically it is an assignment based on pointers and so we are restricted to use the cstring and string library as writing some of the functions of the library was also the part of the assignment other libraries are allowed only string class string library and cstring library are not allowed

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: no i just want a way to change theline number if user exceeds 60 characters and not when he presses enter rather on the runtime dynamically

Comment: Look at how to do non-buffered input then.

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullahCheema With the standard c++ functions you cannot achieve input unless the enter key is pressed. Reading from the keyboard directly is OS specific and you have to find the appropriate functions that allow you to do so.

Comment: is there any way cun.getline stops if user exceed a specif number of characters

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullahCheema As mentioned, no there isn't a way. You have to intercept key presses directly to do so. As also mentioned these are functions beyond the c++ standard library. In case you are using Turbo-C++ check what's available in `conio.h`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> now what i have to achieve is that a single line contains only 60 characters and if the user exceeds 60 characters in input it should automatically shift to the next line

You can't do that using the standard c++ buffered input from `std::cin` and `std::getline()`, because all input needs to be triggered using the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.

You'll need to intercept any key presses directly scanning for keyboard input events. This is OS specific functionality which isn't covered by the C++ standard library.

There are 3rd party libraries like [`ncurses`](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile-ncurses/manual/html_node/Getting-characters-from-the-keyboard.html) though, that allow you to do so in a mostly platform independent manner.

Comment: can you please elaborate something about ncurses as i am a newbie

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullahCheema Check [the link](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile-ncurses/manual/html_node/Getting-characters-from-the-keyboard.html). That should be elaborate enough.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot limit the amount of characters input by the user through the standard c++ libraries.